# Set listItem text color in C# code

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, foreground

I have a listBox, which obviously get filled up with list items through data binding. As you'll also probably know is that you specify what a listItem would look like with a listItem template tag like so:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <TextBlock Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="black" />
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Notice that the Foreground is black on the listItems Textbloxk...

Now in my C# code I'd like to dynamically set each listItems Textblock Foreground to which ever color I want. How does one reference a specific listItems Textblock and set the Foreground of it?

If any more info is needed, please ask! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and easier solution would be to add a property to your items of type SolidColorBrush representing the color, lets call id ForegroundColor and use a binding

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <TextBlock Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" />
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Definitely agree that this is the best way to go about it yes. How does one set a property for a SolidColorBrush variable? e.g what do you send to the constructor? A String perhaps like so: SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush("#FFFFFF"); ?

Comment: Use `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)` or if you want to use the hexa notation, take a look at http://coding.kulman.sk/converting-hex-color-to-solidcolorbrush/

Comment: While that answer is correct, I think it is important to note that adding Style properties on a Model class can sometimes be considered as a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to do it in the code-behind?

The preferred solution would be to bind the `Foreground` property to a ForegroundColor property of your ViewModel (if you use MVVM).

If you don't use MVVM and don't want to 'pollute' your model class with a `Brush` property, you could bind the `Foreground` property to a property you already have in your class (e.g `Name` or `Age`) and use a `Converter` to make it a `Brush`:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <TextBlock Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Age, Converter={StaticResource AgeToColorConverter}}" />
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And the code of the converter:

```
public class AgeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Your code that converts the value to a Brush
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```